# MultiAutoComplete Selected items

Tags: android, autocomplete

i have a multiautocomplete text box which i populate with a list of contacts using a custom adapter. That is working. What i want to know is how do i get the list of selected items(i.e e-mails) from this?
My autocomplete text box is like this

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView act=(MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.attende_list);
     ContentResolver content = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = content.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,PEOPLE_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        ContactListAdapter adapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, cursor, true);
        act.setThreshold(2);
        act.setAdapter(adapter);
        act.setTokenizer(
                new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

Where `ContactListAdapter` is my custom adapter for retrieving the contact mail ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] toArr =   act.getText.toString().split(",");

for(int i=0;i<toArr.length;i++)
{
   System.out.println("Email is "+toArr[i]);
}
```

Check in `logcat` the list of emails are printed which you have selected.

Comment: should this be implemented in the 'onclick' listner of the multiautocomplete textbox?

Comment: are you using any additional buttons for finding contacts

Answer (score 0):

I think you can directly get the string from TextView and split it to get array

```
String [] items = act.getText().toString().split(",");
```